# I am playing unlist youtube video to my app by using youtube android player api how many user can access it in one time

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, youtube-api

What I have done in my app.

1. I  manually upload videos to youtube and make them unlist not public or
   private by using the youtube website
   [youtube unlist video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO6sM.png)
2. Manually stored youtube video URL to Firebase Firestore database
3. then I retrieve the URL from the Firestore database to my app and play video
   using youtube android  player API

question 1. is it the right way do please suggest that or if you any other idea question 2. how many user can play video at one time in my app

Answer (score 0):

> question 1. Is it right way do please suggest on that or if you any other idea question

Yes, that's the right solution for storing the URL of the youtube video. You can store it either in [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or in the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database).

> question 2. How many users can play video at one time in my app?

As far as I know, there is no limitation on the number of users that can watch a youtube video.